# Values getting Overflowed while converting Bit into TB

Tags: c, windows, overflow, bit, long-double

I am making a calculator for converting bits, bytes, MB, KB, GB, TB, EB, PB into each other. Right now I am converting my bit value (1,000,000) into TB using a long double data type because float is giving `0.0000` as definitely the result is out the range. But while I am using long double, its giving me its smallest possible value `-2.863e+36`, instead of giving me the actual result: `0.0001220703125` which should fall in range.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    double valueInBits = 1000000.0; // 1 million bits (use double for floating-point precision)

    // converting valueInBits into TB
    valueInBits = valueInBits / 8.0;
    valueInBits = valueInBits / 1024.0;
    valueInBits = valueInBits / 1024.0;
    valueInBits = valueInBits / 1024.0;
    valueInBits = valueInBits / 1024.0;

    printf("%f TB", valueInBits);
}
```

Comment: Try `%.15f` instead for your format string. https://godbolt.org/z/bG7M6WvYP

Comment: The code posted prints “0.000000 TB”, not “-2.863e+36”, albeit `main` should be declared to return `int`, not `void`. Voting to close as not reproducible. Fix the declaration of `main`, and check that the code you are compiling and executing is exactly the code you think it is. Also −2.863e+36 is not the smallest possible value in the commonly used types. Why do you think it is? (Also note, those are [KiB, MiB, GiB, and TiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix), not kB, MB, GB, and TB.)

Comment: How can 1 million bits be 0.0001220703125 **TB** ?